# Wie unterschreibt man eine Nachricht von mehreren Personen?

Tags: letter

Ich bin gerade dabei eine Einladung von fünf Kollegen an das gesamte Team zu verschicken.

Aber wie unterschreibt man diese Nachricht?

> Viele Grüße
>
> Name1, Name2 ... Name4, mein Name

Oder nur

> Viele Grüße
>
> mein Name

Bzw. gibt es noch eine andere Möglichkeit?

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass es da einen Unterschied zwischen dem Deutschen und anderen Sprachen gibt, beziehungsweise Regeln dafür existieren. Wie würde man es in deiner Muttersprache ausdrücken? Hauptsache die Empfänger wissen wer sie eigentlich einläd und die Kollegen fühlen sich nicht übergangen.

Comment: Ich habe die Mail bereits verschickt ... und mich für die zweite Variante entschieden. Aber natürlich habe ich in der Mail das ganze Team einlädt

Answer (score 3):

Hm, das ist wirklich eine gute Frage, ich habe vor so einem Problem bisher noch nie gestanden. Ich würde aber wahrscheinlich versuchen, von dem "Viele Grüße" wegzukommen.
Das

> Viele Grüße
>   Name1, Name2 ... Name4, mein Name

Hört sich zwar nicht verkehrt an, aber eventuell ist ja auch sowas möglich:

> Wir würden uns über Ihr Erscheinen freuen
>   Name1, Name2 ... Name4, mein Name

Ansonsten ist vielleicht auch sowas möglich, vorausgesetzt man ist ein "offizielles Team"

> Viele Grüße
>   Das Marketing, Projektteam, etc...

Comment: Ich habe einen Mix aus der deiner zweiten Variante und meiner zweiten Variante gemacht. Ich habe in meiner Mail erwähnt von wem die Einladung kommt und habe die Mail wie folgt abgeschlossen: Wir werden uns sehr freuen viele von Euch am nächsten Freitag zu sehen.

Viele Grüße
mein Name